# How to pull data from only the first and last lines of a text file

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a long running program, my_prog that has some output that I want to parse to get two variables, $start and $end.  Here's what the output might look like:

```
Important data between the first set of pipes|3|a|
This line is not interesting to me|5|c|
...
Another line with data (at the end this time)|4|b|
```

In the example above, I just need:

```
start=3
end=b
```

I'm using this in a bash script.  I have a feeling awk can totally solve this issue, but doing a `start=$(my_prog|awk ...)` will give only one variable.  I guess I could do a `my_array=($(my_prog|awk ...))`, but that just seems messy.  Also, I don't want to put the (possibly long) output of my_prog into a variable.  What's a good, simple way to get that data?  Can awk somehow write directly to the bash variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @Zack wrote awk script is ok, the only improvement could be:

```
read start end < <(my_prog | 
  awk -F\| 'NR==1 { start=$2 } END { print start " " $3 }')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it (totally untested):

```
startend=$(my_prog | 
    awk -F\| 'NR==1 { start=$2 } { end=$3 } END { print start "|" end }')
start=${startend%|*}
end=${startend#*|}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to do an assignment on each line of the file. The last record is available in the `END` clause so you won't even need to do an assignment there.

Also, AWK keeps a separate OFS (output field separator) so you can use a comma between your output variables when you print them.

```
delim=" "   # or choose one that suits you
read -r -d "$delim" start end < <(my_prog | 
  awk -F\| -v OFS="$delim" 'NR==1 { start=$2 } END { print start, $3 }')
```

Alternatively, instead of process substitution `< <()`, you can use a here string or a here doc:

```
read ... <<< $(my_prog ...)
```

or

```
read ... <<EOF
$(my_prog ...)
EOF
```

To neaten up the read assignment, you can put your my_prog/awk pipe in a function:

```
foo () { my_prog | awk ... ; }

read ... < <(foo)    # or one of the other redirection methods
```

Answer (score 0):

One could also eval:

 `` eval `myprog | awk -F\| 'NR==1 { start=$2 } { end=$3 } END { print "start="start " end="end }'` ``

Comment: not that I did not used eval ever, but it's quite hardcore way to assign two variable values, prefered would be read from subprocess

    read a b < <(echo "1 2")